# How do I tile two displays onto one monitor with AMD graphics

Tags: xorg, amd-graphics, xinerama, twinview

I have a **Dell UP2414Q** monitor from 2014 that is using two tiles. The left and right side are basically a separate monitor, and DisplayPort's [Multi-Stream Transport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#Multi-Stream_Transport_(MST)) sends a signal to both.

On Windows, this works out of the box.

On Linux, there are two problems. 1: Both halves are separate. Only one half has the task bar, and full-screening anything goes to one of the halves. And 2: The halves are swapped. Right half is left.

For nVidia, this fixed the two issues:

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"

    Option         "TwinView"
    Option         "TwinViewXineramaInfoOverride" "3840x2160+0+0"
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DP-0.9, DP-0.8"
    Option         "metamodes" "DP-0.8: 1920x2160 +1920+0, DP-0.9: 1920x2160 +0+0"
EndSection
```

Now I can't figure out how to do this on a new AMD Picasso Raven APU computer running the amdgpu driver. There is Xinerama, which is old. There is also this [new "tiling" support](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Radeon-AMDGPU-TILE-Support) for this specific case. I can't figure out how to use either.

**How do I use my Dell UP2414Q with MST over DP on my _AMD Ryzen 5 3400G?**

#### Specs:

- Linux Mint 19.2
- Cinnamon 4.2
- Kernel 5.2.0
- Radeon Vega Graphics
- AMD/ATI Picasso

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, MST is broken on the kernel layer for 5.1+ kernels [bug](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=110671). It's quite weird that it's working on your setup.

In userspace we have TILE property in xrandr and [this bug](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=105651) [and this](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-65457)
First one is already fixed(at least in 5.3.0-rc3)

For Cinnamon, if gtk use xrandr monitors feature, than just make sure you have xf86-video-amdgpu-19.0.1 installed [link](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Radeon-AMDGPU-TILE-Support)

If not, you could try something like this barely working hack that I use for KDE:

```
xrandr --screen 0 --setmonitor DellUP2715K 5120/597x2880/336+0+0 DisplayPort-0,DisplayPort-1
xrandr --output DisplayPort-0 --mode 2560x2880
xrandr --output DisplayPort-1 --mode 2560x2880 --pos 0x0 --panning 5120x2880+0+0/0x0+2560+0/-2560/0/-2560/0

xrandr --fbmm 597x336
```

Just change values and put it in your xinitrc.d, and try some magic manipulations with your DM(like changing primary display).

UPD: 597x336 - dimensions of your screen in mm

Comment: Interesting. For me, 5.1 does not work, and 5.3 does not work. I need 5.2 with amdgpu 18.0.1. I'd like to try the `xrandr` commands. I imagine I need `1920x2160` in stead of `2560x2880`, but what are those `597` and `336` numbers? What do they do and where can I find the correct numbers for my monitor?